# querySelectorAll not accepting variable

Tags: javascript, html, css, selectors-api

Okay, this one has me scratching my head.  I've got **getDataArrayForTargetColumn** defined:

```
async getDataArrayForTargetColumn() {
    if (await page.waitForSelector('[data-test-value-invoice-number-payment-requests-page="true"]')) {
        let targetColumnDataArray = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[data-test-value-invoice-number-payment-requests-page="true"]'));
            return tds.map(td => td.textContent.trim());
        });
        return targetColumnDataArray;
    }
    return settings._neg_1;
}
```

and **getDataArrayForTargetColumn2** defined:

```
async getDataArrayForTargetColumn2(someCssSelector) {
    if (await page.waitForSelector(someCssSelector)) {
        let targetColumnDataArray = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(someCssSelector));
            return tds.map(td => td.textContent.trim());
        });
        return targetColumnDataArray;
    }
    return settings._neg_1;
}
```

And when called:

```
async verifySomething{
    let columnData = await this.getDataArrayForTargetColumn();
    let someCssSelector = '[data-test-value-invoice-number-payment-requests-page="true"]';
    let columnData2 = await this.getDataArrayForTargetColumn2(dog);
}
```

The first one, columnData, works and the second one, columnData2, does not.  columnData2 gives me a:

Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: someCssSelector is not defined

but it clearly is.  When I put breakpoints, it seems to die at the **let targetColumnDataArray = await page.evaluate(() => {**

So, what's going on folks?  Why can't I pass a variable in?   Am I missing something stupid here?

============================================================

UPDATE:

This still doesn't work if I move the defining the CSS Selector to within the local function.

```
async getDataArrayForTargetColumn2() {
    let someCssSelector = '[data-test-value-invoice-number-payment-requests-page="true"]';
    if (await page.waitForSelector(someCssSelector)) {
        let targetColumnDataArray = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let tds = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(someCssSelector));
            return tds.map(td => td.textContent.trim());
        });
        return targetColumnDataArray;
    }
    return settings._neg_1;
}
```

Comment: The evaluated function is serialized and deserialized. It does not have the standard lexical scoping that you'd expect in all other normal areas of JS.

Comment: I'm still confused.  Even when I define the CSS Selector local to the function, it is not being passed into the querySelectAll, but it is being evaluated by the page.waitForSelector.   Why is this happening?

Comment: Read the duplicate and its answers more closely. You'll note that the answers recommend passing the variable as a parameter to the arrow function passed to `evaluate`. In your case, `page.evaluate((someCssSelector) => { ... }, someCssSelector)`.

Comment: The function containing the `waitForSelector` call does not get serialized, so `someCssSelector` is available normally, as you'd expect. But the *callback* passed to `page.evaluate` gets serialized into a string and does not have the normal intuitive outer lexical scope availability you'd expect in nearly any other area of JS.